# TeamCity is unable to execute command atlas-clean and atlas package

Tags: teamcity, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am using teamcity to create package of my atlas project.
Giving two command to teamCity in custom script field as bellow:

atlas-clean --file "D:\Data\BambooTaskPlugin\bamboopluginbuild"

atlas-package --file "D:\Data\BambooTaskPlugin\bamboopluginbuild"

These commands are executed successfully on Command prompt but not in teamcity.
TeamCity gives error:
**'atlas-clean' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

If anyone have idea about this, please reply.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to run the same commands on TeamCity agent machine under the same user that the agent is running under? See the related [section|https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Common+Problems#CommonProblems-BuildfailsorbehavesdifferentlyinTeamCitybutnotlocally] in the TeamCity doc.

Comment: Thanks Alina for your response. I have given full path of atlas-clean.bat file then it worked. But now i am unable to run atlas-package command. It gives error: No plugin found for prefix 'D' in the current project and in the plugin groups. How can I provide this?